# Finding two maximum valued Object in python

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, class, decision-tree

I wrote a class to keep three variables column-name, cut-value and info-gain [1]. I'm feeding this in a for loop, like this:

```
def best_split(X, y):
 best_gain=0
 Leaf_collection = []

 for column in X:
  ....
  info_gain = f(column, y)
  if info_gain >= best_gain:
    best_gain= info_gain
    Leaf_colletion.append(Leaf(column, value, info_gain))

 return Leaf_collection
```

Now, the purpose is to filter out these two special cases in the iris dataset, where the info_gain is same for two column-values:

```
column ; value ;  info-gain
petal width (cm) ; 0.6 ; 0.5893309047577491
petal length (cm); 1.9 ; 0.5893309047577491
```

Any suggestion on how one could do it either in this same for loop or afterwards, finding some max. I tried an approach of finding a max, but that filtered out only one case out of two sadly. :(

Many thanks,

[1]

```
class Leaf:

def __init__(self, column, value, info_gain):
    self.column = column //string
    self.value = value // float 
    self.info_gain = info_gain //float
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep track of all leaves, then filter at the end:

```
def best_split(X, y):
    best_gain = 0
    Leaf_collection = []

    for column in X:
        # ....
        info_gain = f(column, y)
        Leaf_collection.append(Leaf(column, value, info_gain))
        best_gain = max(best_gain, info_gain)

    # return all leaves with best gain
    return [
        leaf for leaf in Leaf_collection if leaf.info_gain >= best_gain
    ]
```